# What is referenceContainer or referenceBlock for Payment method in Magento2

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I am trying to override `cc.phtml` file in Magento2 in my payment method,
but I did not find Proper `referenceBlock` or `referenceContainer`.

Like this way,

```
    <referenceContainer name="checkout.onepage.review.info.items.after">
        <block class="Magento\Payment\Block\Transparent\Form" name="payment.form.transparent">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Payment::transparent/form.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

I need the name of Container or Block for payment Section,

hope this will be helpfull for my question.

Answer (score 1):

**--For multi shipping address:**

As far as I know, Magento 2 set this template in the block.

**vendor/magento/module-payment/Block/Form/Cc.php**

```
class Cc extends \Magento\Payment\Block\Form
{
   /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'Magento_Payment::form/cc.phtml';
    .....

}
```

So, in our custom payment module, we can set the template in `_construct()` method

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Payment\Block\Form;

class Cc extends \Magento\Payment\Block\Form\Cc
{
    /**
    * Internal constructor. Set template
    *
    * @return void
    */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('payment/form/cc.phtml');
    }
}
```

**--For one page checkout:**

Magento 2 used html template to render the checkout form. This part is hard if we don't have strong Javascript skill.

**vendor/magento/module-payment/view/frontend/web/template/payment/cc-form.html**

However, we can create our own cc in your custom module. For example, in your payment html template form.

**Vendor/Payment/view/frontend/web/template/payment/form.html**

```
<!-- ko template: 'Vendor_Payment/payment/cc-form' --><!-- /ko -->
```

We can take a look **vendor/magento/module-payment** for more details about the workflow.

Comment: yes, I try to override same template with xml but I didnot find name of referenceBlock or referenceContainer.

Comment: You're working with multi shipping or one page checkout?

Comment: I am working with default checkout with porto theme.

Answer (score 0):

you have to just override xml file into your module,sales_order_create_index.xml file with  **referenceBlock** is **order_create_billing_form**

**magento2/app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_index.xml**
Now insert code,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceBlock name="order_create_billing_form">
                <action method="setMethodFormTemplate">
                    <argument name="method" xsi:type="string">custompayment</argument>
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Modulename::form/cc.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </body>
    </page>
```

you can get more info from default braintree payment method file,

```
vendor/magento/module-braintree/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_index.xml
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to replace default cc.phtml for frontend payment section,

Comment: you have to just create block for that and overrider your phtml inside your block view/frontend/templates/form/cc.phtml  view file

Comment: I tried as mention @khoa-truongdinh, but In payment method section I did not get my edited file,

I think best way if I got referenceBlock name so I will set template with xml,
like you did for adminhtml.

Comment: referenceBlock is for your case is order_create_billing_form